# Drivers problems in Asus Zenbook on Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, usb, drivers, zenbook

I've upgraded my Asus Zenbook UX31E to Windows 8, and ever since the upgrade, the USB  and card reader have stopped working.

The problem appears to be with the Intel Chipset driver and the Fresco USB3 drivers. I've downloaded them both from Asus website for Windows 8 64bit and they both install, but the problem remains.

Does anyone have an idea of how to fix this?

Comment: Did you try to install the Windows 7 version of the drivers?

Comment: I would contact Asus support for assistance.

Comment: I'll try contacting Asus support, but from what I've seen so far, their support is a bit lacking. I tried installing Windows 7 drivers without success

Comment: Found the problem, I uninstalled the USB Charger+ application and it all began to work. Thanks folks! Happy holidays

Comment: @JonathanPerry if you put that as an answer, I'll upvote it.

Comment: @Cupcake You're right, I've posted it as an answer, thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution: Just uninstall the USB charger+ application and the USB card reader should begin to function again. Weird, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

I was also having speed problems with USB 3 on my Asus Zenbook Prime UX31A, but for a different reason.  It turns out that Asus doesn't provide any USB 3 drivers for this model for Windows 8, which I had installed on my machine.

I ended up re-installing Windows 7, along with the appropriate USB 3 driver (some kind of Intel driver), and then I was able to get super-fast USB 3 speeds (up to 140 MB/s for an external 7200 rpm HDD, and up to a blazing fast 230-250 MB/s with a Supersonic Magnum USB flash drive).